# System.Net: Is there any other class inherited from ICredentials apart from NetworkCredential?

Tags: .net, security

Is there any other class inherited from ICredentials in standard .Net libraries, apart from NetworkCredential?
Probably, not only in System.Net namespace.

It looks like [MSDN site page about ICredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.NET.ICREDENTIALS%29;k%28VS.OBJECTBROWSER%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29&rd=true) does not contain this information...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ones I can find are:

- [`CredentialCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.aspx)
- [`NetworkCredential`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential.aspx)
- `SystemNetworkCredential` (which is internal)